# Cordova project launch WhiteListPlugin error when compile in Android Studio

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I´ve migrated recently a IBM MobileFirst 7.0 project to a MobileFirst 8.0, which is a cordova project with MobileFirst plugins. I´ve followed the instructions described here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/upgrading/migration-cookbook/

The problem is an error related to WhiteListPlugin, and more specifically the file ConfigXmlParser.java located in CordovaLib. When compile the project with Android Studio, it launch the error:

```
error: no suitable method found for parse(Context)
method ConfigXmlParser.parse(Activity) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Context cannot be converted to Activity)
method ConfigXmlParser.parse(XmlResourceParser) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Context cannot be converted to XmlResourceParser)
```

Does someone know how to solve this problem? I think the problem is due to an error when importing cordova libraries but I do not know how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Greetings.

Comment: Can you please give the output of cordova plugin list?

Comment: Sure, this is the result of executing the command 'cordova plugin list': 
 
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.11.0 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2018090313 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation"
cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore 8.0.2018080605 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation JSONStore"
cordova-plugin-mfp-push 8.0.2018072407 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation - Push Notifications"
cordova-plugin-okhttp 2.0.0 "OkHttp"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"